# handleRemove function for Todo List app with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am making this app super simple, however I can't get my handleRemove to work properly. filteredTodos comes out to be a list of all the same todos. This is my code.
I have tried even looking at other solutions online but for some reason this filter function in handleRemove does not filter anything out of the state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      inputValue: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newTodo = this.state.inputValue;

    if (this.state.inputValue === ''){
      alert('Please Enter a Todo!');
    } else {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          todos: [...prevState.todos,
            {
              message: newTodo,
              id: this.state.todos.length
            }
          ]
        }));
        this.setState({inputValue:''});
    }
  }

  handleRemove (id) {
    const filteredTodos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
      this.setState({
        todos: filteredTodos
      });

      console.log(filteredTodos);
    }

  render(){
    const mappedTodos = this.state.todos.map((item, i) => 
      <div key={i} id={this.state.todos[i].id}>
        {item.message} <button type='submit' onClick={this.handleRemove}>X</button>
      </div>
    )

    return(
      <div className='main-page'>
        <div className='input'>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Enter Your Todo' value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <button type='submit' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Add</button>
        </div>

        <div className='todos'>
          {mappedTodos}
        </div>

      </div>
     )
    }
   }
   export default Main;
```

Comment: Your `handleRemove` function need an id to work. You can call your function like this : `onClick={() => this.handleRemove(i)}` to call the function with parameter

Comment: Oh dude that worked perfectly. Thanks so much! Any suggestion on where I can learn more about that? Not sure what to look up exactly cause I've tried a lot of searches and never saw anything discuss that method.

Comment: You can go here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I actually just noticed after returning to this project, that this doesn't allow me to delete the last 1-2 items in the array. I can delete any todo in any order, until the last 1-2 then it does nothing. Any idea why that might be @ghuntheur ?

Answer (score 1):

Your handleRemove function requires an id you can see it by the value in the round brackets

```
handleRemove (id)
```

to fix the problem you just have to pass the parameter just like this:

```
const mappedTodos = this.state.todos.map((item, i) => 
      <div key={i} id={this.state.todos[i].id}>
        {item.message} <button type='submit' onClick={this.handleRemove(this.state.todos[i].id)}>X</button>
      </div>
    )
```

Comment: That breaks everything, I get this 'Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.'
I already bind the handleRemove in my constructor so that shouldn't be a problem by my understanding.